# Sequelize Order By Included Model Property

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm trying to order by on a `belongsToMany` relationship. I would like to order by the column `firstName` of the `Subscriptions` table, which is returned with the event.getSubscriptions() query. Here's where I'm at right now:

```
return event.getSubscriptions({
  where: {
    id: {
      $ne: event.currentUserId
    }
  },
  order: // I would like to order by the Subscription.firstName column
})
```

How can I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this

```
return event.getSubscriptions({
  where: {
    id: {
      $ne: event.currentUserId
    }
  },
      order: 'firstName'
})
```

for descending just change order : 'firstName DESC'